# Android Crash Report - Native crash at /system/lib/libc.so caused by webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

A user with a Galaxy Note4 with Android 5.0 had my app crash yesterday. This was the stack trace.

My app is mostly just a webview wrapper of a website. Is there anything I can do to improve the webview or make it more efficient to prevent the 20 or so crashes I'm getting a week that all have this same stack trace?

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/trlteuc/trlteatt:5.0.1/LRX22C/N910AUCU2COC6:user/release-keys'
Revision: '12'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: 421, tid: 421, name: ****.app  >>> org.***********.app <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Abort message: '[FATAL:jni_android.cc(249)] Check failed: false. Please include Java exception stack in crash report
'
    r0 00000000  r1 000001a5  r2 00000006  r3 00000000
    r4 b6fd3114  r5 00000006  r6 0000000b  r7 0000010c
    r8 b6fb2e04  r9 be972e14  sl 00000000  fp b3be8ac4
    ip 000001a5  sp be972968  lr b6f5cff5  pc b6f7f9fc  cpsr 600f0010

backtrace:
    #00 pc 000369fc  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
    #01 pc 00013ff1  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+52)
    #02 pc 00014c0f  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
    #03 pc 00011531  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+36)
    #04 pc 0000fcbc  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
    #05 pc 002b8bf9  /data/app/com.google.android.webview-1/lib/arm/libwebviewchromium.so
```

Comment: There should be a Java exception stack, as the message suggests. Can you please obtain it?

Comment: How can I get that from the Google Play Developer Console? The only info that is provided is what is listed above.

Comment: @MikhailNaganov Any thoughts on above ^ ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very much familiar with Play Developer Console. If it doesn't provide you with both native and Java stacktraces, then the best thing you can do is obtaining a similar device and trying to reproduce the issue yourself -- I assume it occurs often enough, otherwise you wouldn't be so worried about it.

Comment: Did you solve it?? I have been reported some similar crash reports... But i can't guess what is the cause

Comment: No haven't solved it.